# Having issues with 2 video cards - 1 AMD and 1 Nvidia, works but is eventually "hanging", cannot CTRL+ALT+F2 but can SSH from another machine

Tags: nvidia, nouveau

My machine worked fine with an MSI and AMD but the fan went on the MSI, I then got an old Nvidia out of my basement and running on that for now and I know I won't get amazing performance but I'd like to see this stop hanging...

The new card that is throwing the problems is Nvidia GeForce GT 730:

```
dblagbro@UbuntuWorkstation:~$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices 
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:08:00.0 == 
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001287sv000010DEsd00000990bc03sc00i00 
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation 
model    : GK208B [GeForce GT 730]
```

I have no ability to startx when running the Nvidia drivers ... it just comes up to the login screen, click my user, it blinks, then back to the login.

The latest supported are supposed to be the nvidia-driver-390 package but that wouldn't work, I have used the latest Nvidia (knowing those weren't supported for my GT 730) without any luck either...

Where I found the latest Nvidia compatible driver info:

https://arcolinux.com/which-nvidia-cards-are-supported-by-which-nvidia-driver/

The only way I can get it to work at all is the nouveau drivers but, those fill my dmesg with this when it hangs:

[ 1697.373788] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373805] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373822] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373840] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373857] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373874] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373891] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373908] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373925] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373943] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: PBDMA0: 80204000 [ILLEGAL_MTHD] ch 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]] subc 0 mthd 0008 data ff000000

[ 1697.373963] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: read fault at 08f7000000 engine 07 [PFIFO] client 06 [PFIFO] reason 03 [VM_LIMIT_EXCEEDED] on channel 9 [00ff4d4000 Xorg[1467]]

[ 1697.373964] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: fifo: fifo engine fault on channel 9, recovering...

[ 1697.374021] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: Xorg[1467]: channel 9 killed!

[ 1701.933441] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: Xorg[1467]: failed to idle channel 6 [Xorg[1467]]

[ 1716.933976] nouveau 0000:08:00.0: Xorg[1467]: failed to idle channel 6 [Xorg[1467]]

dblagbro@UbuntuWorkstation:~$

.
.

So, I think this is a bug in nouveau working with the GT 730 Nvidia chip and the Ubuntu 20.04 OS...  but this is really outside my expertise and I can't find much more than that above...  knowing the Nvidia proprietary drivers should work too with the 390 version or earlier, I can't seem to get that working either....

Really hoping for any input, I can't keep rebooting my workstation 10x a day because its crashing due to this video card driver issue...  thanks in advance for any help anyone may have.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  It was a bad card, same problems in a different PC it was tried in.

Update:  I don't know if it was the card or drivers...  I ended up taking the fan off this old Nvidia card causing the issues and moving to the other card that I had where the fan broke which was why I went to the old nvidia card in the first place.

Personally, I have not had good experience with Nvidia cards on Ubuntu OSs...  not saying it's something someone can't fix but I have had too many troubles with them to bother trying anymore and I prefer AMD or others over Nvidia now.

Hope this helps.